# Cross-platform file path building and representation

Tags: java, cross-platform, filepath

I am in a refactoring stage for a project I am working on and would like to make some improvements to how I build and represent file system paths. What things should I take into consideration when representing relative paths in Java code to ensure compatibility on Ubuntu, OSX, and Windows 7.

Currently to get an instance of File referencing "MyProject/foo/bar.f" I would have code along the lines of:

`File bar = new File(ProjectDirectory + "/" + FooResourceDirectory + "/" + barName);`

This seems wrong for several reasons, what are some of the best practices?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps use the constructors provided to do this sort of thing:

```
new File(parent, child)
```

You have to "nest" them, but it's trivial to handle this (e.g. make a function to get a path built from something taking `string...`.)

See the [File constructors.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: File.pathSeparator is part what I was originally looking for, but I think I like the idea of using the built in constructors, and nesting/having a wrapper function more.

Answer (score 9):

First of all you should use  `File.separator`
<strike>`File.pathSeparator`</strike> instead of "/".

Comment: Attention: File.pathSeparator != File.separator  -- File.pathSeparator (for example "/")is the character to separate parts of one path, and File.separator (for example ";") is the character to separate different Paths

Comment: I prefer to use the correct constructor through: `new File(parent, child)`

Comment: @Ralph i think you mixed that up. ";" <-> "/"